# Closing a question because it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I tried to give a close vote to the question [Abkürzungen mit Bindestrich](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/70074/34192) because imo it does not belong to "German Language".

In the question "Why should this question be closed?" I selected "A community-specific reason" and then "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network". But after that I had to answer the question "What site does this question belong on?" and the **only** choice was "belongs on german.meta.stackexchange.com". This does not make sense, I would expect that one can select any community in the Stack Exchange network.

Is this a mistake or is intended? If it should be intended, I suggest to enlarge the choices.