# Begrenzte Auswahl bei "This question belongs on another site"

Tags: bug

Ich habe eine Frage entdeckt, die nicht nach German.Stackexchange gehört, sondern in einen anderen Bereich des Stackexchange-Universums. Im konkreten Beispiel geht es um diese Frage:

[Is there a generator of lists of words with a specific category of meaning?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/72747/1487)

Darin wird ausdrücklich nach einer Software-Empfehlung gefragt, und genau für solche Fragen gibt es [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). Also wollte ich die Frage schließen, und dabei angeben, dass sie eigentlich nach softwarerecs.stackexchange.com verschoben werden sollte.

Also klicke ich auf *Close* und wähle dort aus:

- **A community-specific reason**
  This question doesn’t meet a German Language Stack Exchange guideline.

Dann

- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Dann komme ich zu einer Liste mit anderen Stackexchange-Seiten, aber diese Liste enthält nur einen einzigen Eintrag (nämlich *German Meta*), und es gibt dort keine Möglichkeit, irgend etwas anderes auszuwählen als eben *German Meta.* Dort gehört die Frage aber nicht hin.

Ich habe mir dann damit beholfen, dass ich *"Other - add a comment"* gewählt habe. Aber wozu gibt es dann den Punkt *"This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"* wenn man dort nur eine einzige Site wählen kann, die in den meisten Fällen nicht die richtige Wahl ist?

Comment: Siehe auch [diese Frage](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1684/2594) und die dort gelisteten Duplikate.

Answer (score 1):

Ich habe die Frage verschoben. Das Vorgehen, das über den Schließungsgrund **Other** abzuwickeln, deckt sich mit meiner Auffassung. [Hier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration/96345#96345) steht außerdem, dass *Meta* zwingend die erste Option ist.

[Diese Meta Frage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276083/how-do-we-specify-migration-targets-for-our-site) lässt vermuten, dass ein Forum mit dem Verlassen der beta-Phase Verschiebungsziele vorgeben kann, ich kann mir aber nicht vorstellen, dass *Software Recommendations* in einer knappen Auswahl enthalten gewesen wäre.

Was wären denn nach Auffassung der geneigten Forumsteilnehmer typische Verschiebungsziele?

---

Der Vorschlag, im Schließungsdialog einfach alle Sites auflisten und nach Nutzungsgrad zu sortieren, steht in eklatantem Widerspruch zur Intention des Betreibers, siehe erster Link.

Comment: Zuerst wäre mal zu klären, ob die Frage automatisch zur angegeben Site verschoben wird wenn sie geschlossen wird, oder ob die Ziel-SIte "nur" eine Empfehlung ist, wobei dann ein Moderator die endgültige Entscheidung zu treffen hätte. Einen Automatismus würde ich ablehnen. Das sollte schon einem Moderator überlassen bleiben.

Comment: Zum Inhalt der Liste: Ich würde da gar keine Site ausschließen, sondern alle existierenden Sites reinnehmen. Und die Liste sollte danach sort werden, wie oft die jeweilige Site tatsächlich schon ein Ziel einer Verschiebung war. Eventuell könnte man das auch so machen, dass man Sites, zu denen noch nie etwas verschoben wurde, erst nach einem zweiten Klick (z.B. auf "other Site") anzeigt.